# How do I code grouped product's children product to open fotorama gallary page when clicking on children product picture?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, grouped-products

How do I code grouped product's children product to open fotorama gallary page when clicking on children product picture?

**Grouped Products Page**
[image]
**Fotorama Gallary Page**
[image]
**Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml edited:**

```
<?php $_item = get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler'); ?>
<?php $readHandler->execute($_item); ?>
<?php $images=$_item->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>

<td>
            <div data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>">
            <img alt="main product photo" class="gallery-placeholder__image" src="<?= $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$childProduct->getImage() ?>" alt width="200"/>
        </div>
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>]": {
                        "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                            "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                            "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                            "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                            "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                            "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                            "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
            </td>
```

Is this correctly added? Isn't data value in script going to be a issue with having specific urls? Is that where $images should be added? I am getting error on line 1 code $_item = get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler');

Answer (score 0):

Add media images in **$_item** object using class
**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler**

```
$readHandler->execute($_item); //$readHandler is object of above mentioned class
```

Get images from item object.

```
$images=$_item->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Add and make URLs dynamic in following HTML for each item and hide/show on click of URL link.

Also make value of attribute **data-gallery-role** dynamic. You can use **$_item->getId()** in place of "1" e.g.

```
data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder-1">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="https://localhost/media/catalog/product/cache/ab3d160fedea4cd0de2e67da8a2de7a6/l/u/luma-yoga-strap.jpg"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder-1]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {"fullscreenzoom":"20","top":"","left":"","width":"","height":"","eventType":"hover","enabled":false,"mode":"outside"},
                "data": [{"thumb":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/078cff84acf01b3300b65566406c4a02\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap.jpg","img":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/ab3d160fedea4cd0de2e67da8a2de7a6\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap.jpg","full":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/77f6e83a0608844e1a4dddeb99e4ea45\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap.jpg","caption":"Image","position":"1","isMain":true,"type":"image","videoUrl":null},{"thumb":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/078cff84acf01b3300b65566406c4a02\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap_1.jpg","img":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/ab3d160fedea4cd0de2e67da8a2de7a6\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap_1.jpg","full":"https:\/\/cert.local.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/77f6e83a0608844e1a4dddeb99e4ea45\/l\/u\/luma-yoga-strap_1.jpg","caption":"Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot","position":"2","isMain":false,"type":"image","videoUrl":null}],
                "options": {"nav":"thumbs","loop":true,"keyboard":true,"arrows":true,"allowfullscreen":true,"showCaption":false,"width":700,"thumbwidth":88,"thumbheight":110,"height":700,"transitionduration":500,"transition":"slide","navarrows":true,"navtype":"slides","navdir":"horizontal"},
                "fullscreen": {"nav":"thumbs","loop":true,"navdir":"horizontal","navarrows":false,"navtype":"slides","arrows":true,"showCaption":false,"transitionduration":500,"transition":"slide"},
                 "breakpoints": {"mobile":{"conditions":{"max-width":"767px"},"options":{"options":{"nav":"dots"}}}}            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advanced code. I am a beginer with coding, but do I add all this into the code file I just shared? grouped.phtml inside Magento_GroupedProduct module?

Comment: No, we should not edit any file under vendor directory.
Override this file in a custom extension or custom theme.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding much. I edited my post and added code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any advice or example how this should look to work?

Comment: Which file(s) you added/edited? Can you share code for all?
What error you are facing?

Comment: I have edited grouped.phtml from path www\app\design\frontend\Vendor_Name\Theme_Name\Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml but I think I have messed up code. You can see the code in first post (Question post) it's edited. Dose my code looks correct or is something wrong there?

Comment: Hello. Your html code is confusing me with your urls. Can you please check my code if it's correct and what I am missing?